# how to pass a value from JavaScript to JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, applet

I have a requirement that I need to get the byte array value from applet to JSP so that I have used JavaScript in my JSP and I got the byte array perfectly but the value is in side the JavaScript method only I need to get that value out side of JavaScript so that I can pass that value to controller class
can any body please tell me the solution 
here is my JavaScript method

```
var bytes=[]; 
function accessAppletMethod()
{
 var a= document.AppletABC.run();
 console.log('byte Array Expected : '+a);
  bytes = a.split('~'); 
    alert("bytes..."+bytes);
```

Comment: use AJAX to send bytes to controller.

Comment: @Rembo  Maybe that should be an answer, though I'm tempted to VTC as 'too broad'..

Comment: can't i put it in request scope and pass to the controller class i just got this idea. if it is correct how can i get this bytes out side of javascript method.

Comment: so that i can pass to controller class